# How much work do I need to do at Hotel Richissime to get each pay raise and what changes for each job at each pay raise?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

How much work do I need to do to get my pay raised from 2,000 to 10,000, 10,000 to 20,000 and 20,000 to 50,000?

And what are the differences in each task at each of those pay points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean what do you have to do for the other tasks?

For the room service, you have to remember 2 dishes and for the making beds task, you have to do the same thing but within 65 seconds.

Your next pay rise will be to 20,000 pokedollars.

---

As per edit:

After 5 perfect tasks, you get promoted and get a pay of 10,000 pokedollars per perfect task.

The tasks then are:

- 65 seconds for bed making;
- 2 lost items to look for;
- 2 dishes to remember and order.

After 15 perfect tasks since your last promotion, you get promoted and get a pay of 20,000 pokedollars per perfect task.

The tasks then are:

- 55 seconds for bed making;
- 3 lost items to look for;
- 3 dishes to remember and order.

After 10 more perfect tasks since your last promotion, you get promoted and get a pay of 50,000 pokedollars per perfect task. The manager of the hotel will see you and welcome you as the best attendant in the hotel but also as a trainer.

The tasks are:

- 45 seconds for bed making;
- 4 lost items to look for;
- 4 dishes to remember and order.

Comment: Sorry I mean for each pay raise and each respective task. Supposedly it goes up to 50,000.

Comment: @Reafexus Sorry, I have edited my answer but haven't reached as far as the 50,000 pay. I'll update when I reach that point.

Comment: @Reafexus That was shorter than I anticipated! Updated my answer!